# having trouble importing python logging

Tags: python, python-logging

I am running Python 3.7.3 and am very new to Python. Trying out the logging module. Please advise what I am doing wrong.

In interactive mode, this works:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.error('test')
```

however when i put it in a .py file, I am getting this error:
`AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'getLogger'`

thanks

Comment: this isn't how I typically define my logger, but it works for me without issue.  Do you have your python path set properly?

Comment: Do you have a module named logging in the same directory?

Comment: thanks for the help. the issue was indeed that my script was named logging.py. smh i should have realized. thanks again

Comment: Thanks, I also named one script as logging.py, and it caused the problem!